# VBA fetch data from string

Tags: excel, vba

Source Data: [image: Source Data Image Sheet]

Data to be pop: [image: Data to be populated Sheet]

I have a String like:

> AV0(25CS,10P,5X)
>
> AV0(10P,5X)
>
> AV0(10P)
>
> AV0(5X)

I have a table with column AV , CS, P , X
I want to populate 0 in the cell below AV , 25 in the cell below CS , 10 in the cell below, 5 in the cell below X.

Please help.

I tried for CS:

```
str = Cells(1, 1).Value 'String Value
openPos = InStr(str, "(")
closePos = InStr(str, ")")
Cells(2, 2) = Mid(str, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1) 'String value to cells
```

Comment: Think you need to provide a bigger sample of data. Are they always in the same format as your single example?

Comment: @SJR: I updated the sample data, Thanks

Comment: QHarr: Yes they always occur in the same format and they are always in UPPER, thanks

Comment: Does your actual data only have the 4 strings or can there be more?

Comment: @SJR Yes maximum it can have 4 string and min 2 like 4P

Answer (score 1):

There is a faff using regular expressions as VBA does not support positive lookbehinds.

I'm not sure how you want to extract the results, I've just done it to the sheet below.

```
Sub Regex2()

Dim oMatches As Object, i As Long, r As Range

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "^AV(\d*)\((\d*CS)*,*(\d*P)*,*(\d*X)*\)$"
    For Each r In Range("A1:A4")
        Set oMatches = .Execute(r)
        For i = 0 To 3
            If oMatches(0).submatches(i) <> "" Then
                If i = 0 Then r.Offset(, 1) = oMatches(0).submatches(0) 'AV
                If i = 1 Then r.Offset(, 2) = Replace(oMatches(0).submatches(1), "CS", "") 'CS
                If i = 2 Then r.Offset(, 3) = Replace(oMatches(0).submatches(2), "P", "") 'P
                If i = 3 Then r.Offset(, 4) = Replace(oMatches(0).submatches(3), "X", "") 'X
            End If
        Next i
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This helps to an extent. I have added 2 sheets one with the exact source data another sheet where data to be populated. Thank you so much for your effort. Please have a look at the sheets.

Comment: I think I would turn it into a function and add the string as a parameter. Also I think that should be a separate question. Have a go yourself at trying to adapt what I've done, if you get stuck start a new question.

Comment: Yes I tried but didn't work with this data please help me with the code.

Comment: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61571509/vba-to-populate-sheet" Please help