# VBA to populate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Source Data Sheet

[image]

Data To be populated sheet

[image]

I have two sheets the source and the sheet where data need to be populated.

I want to fetch the numeric value from the source sheet under the corresponding column of the other sheet.

I tried this

I tried with my code adding it but its going wrong somewhere can u please check. Considering my data is already formatted with , .

```
Sub pop_codes() '
    Dim wsdata, wsPop As Worksheet
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLoop2 As Long
    Dim aData() As String
    Dim strData As String
    Dim DataLastRow As Integer
    Dim DataLastCol As Integer
    Set wsdata = Sheets("SourceData")
    Set wsPop = Sheets("TempData")
    DataLastRow = wsdata.Cells(wsdata.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    DataLastCol = wsdata.Cells(1, wsdata.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    OutputRow = 2
    SearchArr = Array("AV", "CS", "P", "X", "FW", "H", "J", "L", "M", "N", "P", "PD", "PK", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "X", "BK", "CP", "FX", "HD", "IP", "IU")
    For OutputRow = 2 To DataLastRow
        For OutputCol = 2 To DataLastCol
           strData = wsdata.Cells(OutputRow, OutputCol)
           ' strData = Replace(strData, ")", ",")
           ' strData = Replace(strData, "(", ",")
           'strData = Replace(strData, " ", "")
            aData() = Split(strData, ",")
            For lngLoop1 = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
                For lngLoop2 = LBound(SearchArr) To UBound(SearchArr)
                    If InStr(aData(lngLoop1), SearchArr(lngLoop2)) > 0 Then
                        wsPop.Cells(OutputRow, 1) = wsdata.Cells(OutputRow, 1)
                        wsPop.Cells(OutputRow, 2) = wsdata.Cells(1, DataLastCol)
                        wsPop.Cells(OutputRow, 3) = SearchArr(lngLoop2)
                        wsPop.Cells(OutputRow, 4) = Replace(aData(lngLoop1), SearchArr(lngLoop2), "")
                        OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
                    End If
                Next lngLoop2
            Next lngLoop1
        Next OutputCol
    Next OutputRow
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbData = Nothing
    Set wsPop = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sDataSource", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is there a `40` in to be populated sheet for `Week3` and `abc@gmail@com`? At the sourcce data sheet it says for `abc@gmail.com` in `week3`: `AV0(40CS)`. Doesn't that mean `AV` is `0`? Please also fill in the remaining empty cells in the to be populated sheet to make it absolutely clear what the result should be.

Comment: Please actually read my code and understand how it works before copying parts of it into your code. Because you have only copied part of it, it is not working properly - for example, you are using `OutputRow` as both the loop counter on the data sheet and also the row number of the temp sheet. Also, the `Replace` functions are needed to get the data into a format that it can be split nicely into an array, so "AV0(25CS, 15P)" becomes "AV0,25CS,15P,"

Comment: @Applecore I already have the data split in the required format as u said , with week and name pre populated.I m just looking on to add conditions for the array and how to populate them to their respective columns.

Comment: The code that I supplied was to split out to a temporary worksheet, parsing out the values for the different names - you will then need additional code populate your final worksheet.

Comment: @Applecore Is there a generic code in the code u gave.which i can use in order to use those search value and populate in columns ?

Comment: Once you have populated the data in your temp sheet, you should be able to use the worksheet functions INDEX & MATCH to get the data into the correct positions on your final worksheet. Something like `=INDEX(TempData!$D:$D,MATCH(1,($A2=TempData!$B:$B)*($B2=TempData!$A:$A)*(C$1=TempData!$C:$C),0))`.

Comment: @Applecore Sorry to ask u again but I m newbie. Can u please help me with the code i need to place on the vba. The above one is a function without a loop

Comment: The worksheet function provided can be just pasted into your final worksheet. Once you have adjusted the cell references, it should pick out the correct values from the temp worksheet that my VBA code populates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a "stepping" worksheet that I would populate with the split data from your first worksheet. This could then be used as the basis for your final worksheet.

Some VBA code to do this would be:

```
Sub sDataSource()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim wsIn As Worksheet
    Dim lngInLastRow As Long
    Dim lngInLastCol As Long
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim strData As String
    Dim aData() As String
    Dim aSearch() As Variant
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLoop2 As Long
    Dim lngOutRow As Long
    Dim lngInRow As Long
    Dim lngInCol As Long
    Set wsIn = Worksheets("SourceData")
    lngInLastRow = wsIn.Cells(wsIn.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lngInLastCol = wsIn.Cells(1, wsIn.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set wsOut = Worksheets("TempData")
    lngOutRow = 2
    aSearch = Array("AV", "BK", "CP", "CS", "FW", "FX", "HD", "IP", "IU", "PD", "PK", "P", "H", "J", "L", "M", "N", "R", "S", "T", "V", "W", "X")
    For lngInRow = 2 To lngInLastRow
        For lngInCol = 2 To lngInLastCol
            strData = wsIn.Cells(lngInRow, lngInCol)
            strData = Replace(strData, ")", ",")
            strData = Replace(strData, "(", ",")
            strData = Replace(strData, " ", "")
            aData() = Split(strData, ",")
            For lngLoop1 = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
                For lngLoop2 = LBound(aSearch) To UBound(aSearch)
                    If InStr(aData(lngLoop1), aSearch(lngLoop2)) > 0 Then
                        wsOut.Cells(lngOutRow, 1) = wsIn.Cells(lngInRow, 1)
                        wsOut.Cells(lngOutRow, 2) = wsIn.Cells(1, lngInCol)
                        wsOut.Cells(lngOutRow, 3) = aSearch(lngLoop2)
                        wsOut.Cells(lngOutRow, 4) = Replace(aData(lngLoop1), aSearch(lngLoop2), "")
                        aData(lngLoop1) = ""
                        lngOutRow = lngOutRow + 1
                    End If
                Next lngLoop2
            Next lngLoop1
        Next lngInCol
    Next lngInRow
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsIn = Nothing
    Set wsOut = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sDataSource", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

In this code, I've looped the worksheet and got the value for each week/user. I've replaced the brackets with commas, and removed any spaces. This has then been split into an array, and I then walk this array, checking for each of the different values (i.e. CS, P, AV, X) that I am looking for. If I find it, then output this element of the array, replacing the text part with an empty string).

Code has been modified to deal with the fact that some data names can cause duplication (i.e. "P" and "CP") when using `InStr()`, and I have dealt with this by putting the two character data names at the start of the array, and if there is a match, then setting the element of the data array to be a zero length string.

Regards,

Comment: I tried your code and update it in the question considering my data is already formatted with ,.
Can u please check the arrays and tweak the code accordingly. At max one cell can have 5 codes. Thanks in tons

Comment: I've modified my code to deal with "P"/"PX"/"CP", where "P" would be found in all 3 cases.

Comment: Thanks, The codes will always be in upper code. How should i add other cases like for S, T,V,W they are columns are numbers having their code should be populated in that??

Comment: Add these to the array `aSearch`, making sure that any single character names are at the end of the array, and 2 character names at the start.

Comment: I want to populate the search items to their corresponding column they are in the same serial which u gave.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy solution for such an elaborated task.

If I were you, I'll first split this into different pages: one page, containing the `AV` results, one with the `CS` results, ...

You also need to find a way to read the contents of the cells, I see following things to be done:

- Remove all `AVO(` and `)` from all cells (at least that's how I understand the task)
- Make a difference between cells, containing a comma, and the ones without (use arrays to store values of cells with commas)
- While reading the contents of the cells, beware of the space (sometimes present (`40 AV`), sometimes not (`40CS`))

Once you have decyphered everything into different pages (and checked the correctness), you might summarise everything into one page.